# SharePoint: Back up single page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I need to back up a sharepoint web page which containts web parts and other html tweaks.  I would like to keep a back up of the page itself with the web parts in the appropriate places, is this possible?  Right now I just opened SharePoint designer, opened my page and saved as to my hard drive.  Is there another way?  Is this a complete back up of the page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same for small changes and it has worked fine for me up to now. That said the only offical way to do it is use Microsoft's Data Protection Manager software which will let you backup/restore individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can go the doclib where the page is stored and use the ECB SendTo>>Download a copy

the interesting part of this approach is that you get the ASP.NET markup (w/server control specs)...